# Calculate cumulative performance

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Suppose a man produces $15$ nos. of item $A$ having cycle time of $8.99 \sec$ in $6 \min$.

**Performance I:**

Cycle Time in seconds $= 8.99$

Total Units Produced $= 15$

Total Runtime in seconds $= 6\times60 = 360$

$$P1 = ((8.99\times15) / 360)\times100=37.48\%$$

---

The same man on same machine produces $218$ nos. of item $B$ having cycle time of $12 \sec$ in $78 \min$.

**Performance II:**

Cycle Time in seconds $= 12$

Total Units Produced $= 218$

Total Runtime in seconds $= 78\times60 = 4680$

$$P2 = ((12\times218) / 4680)\times100=55.89\%$$

> So how can get his overall performance of complete $6 + 78 = 84 \min$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add up the total working time and divide by the total time
$$\frac {8.99\cdot 15+12\cdot 218}{60\cdot 84}\approx 54.58\%$$
This is close to the second phase because the second phase is most of the total time.